# Json Request only fetching one object despite using a loop

Tags: java, android, json

I am making my first Android Studio project. I have written code so that all corresponding json data from a given url should be fetched and display in a list.I'm using a Json Array Request for this and running a loop. However I am only getting the first json object not all.

I have gotten results with identical java code before. Could this be a layout issue?

Here is the Java:

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(newurl, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            //@Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                for (int i=0;i<response.length(); i++){
                  try{
                      JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                      Tags tag = new Tags();
                      tag.setTag(jsonObject.getString( "tag"));
                      tag.setTitle(jsonObject.getString( "title"));
                      tagsList.add(tag);
                  }
```

There definitely is more than one object. How can I solve this?

Comment: My bad, wasn't aware of this.

Comment: probably the `response` has only 1 item, probably the #2 item parsing causes exception, probably it is lost somewhere else.

Comment: can you print the response.length() so that you can verify that you actually get multiple data